# Can't append values to a list in R

Tags: r, list

I got a list with a weird format:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "Freq.2432.40862794099" "Freq.2792.87280096993" "Freq.2955.16577598796"
 [4] "Freq.3161.12982491516" "Freq.3194.19720315405" "Freq.3218.83311568825"
 [7] "Freq.3265.37951283662" "Freq.3317.86908506493" "Freq.3900.50408838719"
[10] "Freq.4073.33935633108" "Freq.4302.8830598659"  "Freq.4404.80065271461"
[13] "Freq.4469.12305573234" "Freq.4567.90688886175" "Freq.4965.4984006347" 
[16] "Freq.5854.45161215455" "Freq.5905.64933878776" "Freq.6175.68130655941"
[19] "Freq.6433.22411185796" "Freq.6631.46775487994" "Freq.6958.20015968149"
[22] "Freq.7469.83422424355" "Freq.8602.43342069553" "Freq.8766.14436081853"
[25] "Freq.8811.22677706485" "Freq.8915.90029255773" "Freq.9131.39810096"   
[28] "Freq.9378.82122607608"
```

Never saw that [[1]] in a list before, and the problem is that I can't append things to this list.
How can I solve this?

Comment: df[[1]] <- c(df[[1]], values_to_add)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a list in a list. Normally this can be referred to as a nested list.

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)
list <- list(a,b)
```

In this code snippet we are creating two vectors and put them into a list. Now you can access the nested vectors/lists using the double brackets. Like so:

```
list[[1]]
> [1] 1 2 3
```

Now, if you want to change the value (or append it, see comment) you can use the normal syntax but solely assign it to the nested object.

```
list[[1]] <- c(7,8,9)
list[[1]]
> [1] 7 8 9
```